# SQL query to get table rows whose columns should not match with other table columns when passing same column id

Tags: mysql

I have two tables carts and checks.
I need a row data of carts table whose orderid column and exam_name column should not match with checks table order_id column and exam column and i am passing `userid = $id` from my php function. Here the userid is same for both the table

**Carts** table:

```
    id |userid | username | orderid             | exam_name |
    1  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | PMP       |
    2  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | CAPM      |
    3  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | Prince2   |
    4  |14     | Rakesh   |678g310v671N888M6720 | Prince2   |
```

**Checks** table:

```
    id |userid | username | orderid             | exam_name |
    1  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | PMP       |
    2  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | CAPM      |
```

I need a row data of carts table whose orderid column and exam_name column should not match with checks table order_id column and exam column and i am passing userid = $id from my php function. Here the userid is same for both the table

```
    1  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | Prince2   |
    2  |14     | Rakesh   |678g310v671N888M6720 | Prince2   |
```

I got the below sql query from reference but its not working

```
 select c.* 
 from carts c 
 where (c.orderid, c.exam_name) not in (select ch.order_id, ch.exam 
                                        from checks ch 
                                        where ch.userid = 13)
```

Comment: Which DBMS using..?

Comment: I am using Mysql Database. I need a row data of carts table whose orderid column and exam_name column should not match with checks table order_id column and exam column and i am passing userid = $id from my php function. Here the userid is same for both the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select c.* from carts c where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM checks WHERE checks.orderid = c.orderid AND c.exam_name = checks.exam_name)
    AND C.userid = 13
```